# How to triage this MySQL duplicate entry error after running Rails migration?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, duplicates

I get the following error when I try to run this migration:

```
==  AddUniquenessConstraintOnAwards: migrating ================================
-- add_index(:awards, [:badge_id, :game_week_id], {:unique=>true, :name=>:game_badge_index})
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql::Error: Duplicate entry '35-8192' for key 'game_badge_index': CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `game_badge_index` ON `awards` (`badge_id`, `game_week_id`)
```

Has anyone encountered?  What's the error telling me?  How did you troubleshoot it and ultimately fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is telling you that there is at least two records in your awards table that have the same values for badge_id and game_week_id (entry 35-8192), and such duplicate entries aren't permitted for a Unique index

To fix it, you eliminate the duplicate records